# how to run tests on amazon device farm using travis CI

Tags: android, travis-ci, aws-device-farm

I want to use travis ci for the build process, It looks like a good option as they have emulators also. But I want to run tests on real devices, like Amazon device farm. I am not able to find relevant documentation for that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there's not direct support for Travis CI.  Admittedly, this is the first I've heard of Travis CI.  If it has the ability to run scripts you can write a script to create and schedule the run in Device Farm.

Hope that helps.